# Disable USB ports for good when PC is off

Tags: usb, motherboard, power-management

I have an USB-power issue from a long ago, and now it became unbearable. The issue is that my motherboard (Asus H97-Pro) doesn't really turns off USB-devices when the PC is off. Keyboard (back-lit) and mouse (have a led too), for example, remain lit when I shutting down my PC.

But now I'm a (not so) proud owner of a PSU, the full title of which is Thermaltake Toughpower DPS G RGB 1000W Titanium. It has a built-in hardware monitor and it connects to motherboard with a USB-cable.

And here the magic kicks in. When PC is off, the PSU emits coil whine. Turns out, if the PSU and MB are connected via the USB-cable, it somehow draws power from the PSU into the MB's system, which causes the chassis fans connected to the MB to remain lit (they have led back-light too). One of the fans is DC-controlled, it don't actually emitting light, but if I turn its rotor manually, it affects the whine tone. So there is an electrical circuit or a loop which causes such effect. Once I plug the USB-cable from the PSU off, the problem is gone.

Another detail. The issue happens only when the PC is turned off from the OS. It doesn't happen if AC power was cut and restored - the PC is in normal stand-by mode. It doesn't happen if the PC was turned on and then off before the OS is loaded. So, assuming that the PSU is remaining in the same state, my bet it's connected to USB power-management. Perhaps the OS sends or not sends some commands, not cutting some circuits off when it should and then the issue happens.

So I'm trying to find a way to cut USB-power in stand-by mode for good. And I can't. Already had played with these settings: [image: https://i.imgur.com/qRGsgLd.png] (sorry, the picture is in Russian, but it is quite obvious from the appearance what the settings are for those who are familiar with them). Searched for some "ERP" setting in BIOS, no luck.

So I'm ran out of versions. Perhaps anyone can suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aight, once again asking questions was just a path to finding an answer by myself.

The option which did the trick was, in my case, enabling "Deep S4 state" in "Advanced/APM" section of BIOS. After that the PC finally turned off, like, for real. Oh the mystery of the last 5-6 years...

No thanks to the Thermaltake and the Asus tech support and communities.

Answer (score 0):

I have a non-reversible suggestion: Sever the +5V wire on the USB connection. Since the USB device in question (your PSU) is apparently self-powered, it does not need power from the USB connection. The ground wire has to stay of course.

Your motherboard does not have a switch to prevent this power flow, because sane USB devices do not behave this way.

Comment: Was thinking about such possibility myself. But the problem appeared only if the PC was powered off from fully loaded OS. So I've found the solution in enabling "Deep S4 state" thing.